# How can you add hotkeys in an angularjs app while the cursor continues to focus on a textfield?

Tags: angularjs, hotkeys

I have an angular app where the user needs the cursor to stay in a search field (due to high user performance needs) but at the same time, user should be able to invoke hotkeys without having to remove the focus from the search text field.

How can we achieve this?

I am using chieffancypants/angular-hotkeys#~1.6.0 plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer:

hotkeys.add({
            combo: 'f2', description: 'Rebox Image',
            allowIn: ['INPUT', 'SELECT', 'TEXTAREA'],
            callback: function () {

```
        }
    });
```